# Как получить массив умений пользователей но при этом что бы не было повторений

Tags: javascript

Я хочу получить  массив всех умений всех пользователей (поле skills), при этом не должно быть повторяющихся умений и они должны быть отсортированы в алфавитном порядке. Вот что у меня получилось следуя этому условию.

```js
'use strict';
const users = [
  {
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
  },
 
  
 
  {
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
  },
];
const getSortedUniqueSkills = users => {
  return users
    .sort((a, b) => a.skills.length === b.skills.length)
    .map(e => e.skills);
};

console.log(getSortedUniqueSkills(users));
```

У меня они повтраются и не сортируются по алфавиту. ожидаемый результат должен быть

```js
[ 'adipisicing', 'amet', 'anim', 'commodo', 'culpa', 'elit', 'ex', 'ipsum', 'irure', 'laborum', 'lorem', 'mollit', 'non', 'nostrud', 'nulla', 'proident', 'tempor', 'velit', 'veniam' ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с ES6 можно использовать тип [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
'use strict';
const users = [
  {
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
  },
 
  
 
  {
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
  },
];
const getSortedUniqueSkills = users => {
  return new Set(users
    .flatMap(user => user.skills)
    .sort());
};

console.log([...getSortedUniqueSkills(users)]);
```

Comment: @hzybodska есть одно уточнение по поводу сортировок строк: сортировка/сравнение строк 'Common' и 'alphabet' будет разная. нужно приводить к одному регистру и сравнивать результаты если вы не уверены в качестве входных данных. Сравнение идет по charCode. Еще есть особенность с более мутными символами, которые находятся где-то там далеко в таблице https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: ну в противном случае не выводилось ничего во встроенн в сниппет консоль...

Answer (score 1):

```js
'use strict';
const users = [
  {
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
  },
  {
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
  },
  {
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
    name: 'Carey Barr',
    email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 27,
  },
  {
    guid: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
    name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
    email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 38,
  },
  {
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
  },
];
const getSortedUniqueSkills = users => {
  return users
    .reduce((allSkills, user) => {
      allSkills.push(...user.skills);
      return allSkills;
    }, [])
    .filter((user, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(user) === index)
    .sort();
};
console.log(getSortedUniqueSkills(users));
```

Comment: я додала еще параметров)